# Binding para un grupo de RadioButton en XAML MVVM

Tags: c#, xaml, wpf

Si agrego un control `RadioButton` y especifico una propiedad en el `ViemModel`, puedo hacer el `Binding` con normalidad, pero si tengo una lista de objetos y creo un `RadioButton` por cada objeto de la lista, ¿cómo se hace para que el `RadioButton` seleccionado haga el `Binding` como `SelectedItem`?

Comment: Bienvenido/a a Stack Overflow en español, podrías agregar parte del código que has intentado hacer hasta ahora?  cual quier cosa aqui tienes sugerencias a la hora de formular preguntas. http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ya revisaste en esta pagina: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton(v=vs.110).aspx Quizá te sirva de ayuda para resolver ese detalle.

Comment: No he aportado código porque no se por donde empezar con este tipo de control en grupo. De hecho, para resolverlo momentáneamente, estoy utilizando un ComboBox, que cumple con el requisito, pero me gustaría poder hacerlo con RadioButton.

Comment: por favor agrega información como: Tienes cada uno de los items de la lista en el template? el RadioButton es parte del template? por lo menos si esto esta deberias mostrar el XAML relevante.

Comment: Hola @Dario he revertido tus cambios. Si ya encontraste la solución crea una nueva respuesta y márcala como aceptada en lugar de editar la pregunta

Comment: Muchas gracias @CarlosMuñoz es mi primera pregunta y me esta costando publicar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enlace con la información que he encontrado:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2284752/mvvm-binding-radio-buttons-to-a-view-model

En el `ViewModel` tengo una colección para generar los `Items` y un objeto para el `SelectedItem`

En la vista, un `ListBox` para mostrar los `Items` convertidos a `RadioButton` así:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Continents}"
             SelectedItem="{Binding Selected}"
             BorderThickness="0"
             ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
             Background="Transparent">            
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">

                            <RadioButton Content="{Binding Name}"
                                         IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={
                                RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsSelected}"/>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}" MethodName="CBSelectionChanged"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </ListBox>
```

Espero que le sirva a alguien.

Comment: no olvides aceptar tu respuesta como correcta.

Comment: Creo que sobran las líneas, <i:Interaction.Triggers> ...</i:Interaction.Triggers>, he conseguido hacerlo funcionar sin ellas.

Comment: Sí, @rauland, esto es sólo para hacer ejecutar un método en el `ViewModel` al ejecutarse el evento `SelectionChanged`.